# How to color code paired entries in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview where every two rows are part of a pair and I would like to keep paired rows the same color for easier reading.

- Row 0: White Background
- Row 1: White Background
- Row 2: Light Gray Background
- Row 3: Light Gray Background
- Row 4: White Background
- Row 5: White Background
- etc.

How can I do this when adding new rows programmatically?
Thanks

Comment: There are some paint events like `RowPrePaint` where you can evaluate data and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attributes to your datagridview tag.

```
this.dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
this.dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: A `GridView` is not the same as a `DataGridView`

Comment: Oops! I edited my answer. Thanks @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp

Comment: This would do:
Row 0: Black
Row 1: Yellow
Row 2: Black